# Eclipse: highlighted line of text illegible in various places

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I just upgraded from Ubuntu MATE 16.04 and Eclipse Luna to Ubuntu MATE 18.04 and Eclipse Oxygen.

After upgrading, I notice that the color combinations for highlighted lines in various places make the text illegible, as background and foreground colors are virtually identical—I had no such issues before the upgrade.

So far I have noticed two places where this happens.

In the drop-down list for the tab selector:

[image: Tab selector dropdown list]

In the popup window which appears when debugging a CDT project in Eclipse and hovering over a variable:

[image: Variable inspector popup]

I had no such issues in my previous setup, and I cannot find a setting for the background color. What gives?

Comment: Could you please try if you have this issue also in the [preview build of Eclipse Photon](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php)?

Comment: I’ll try on my test VM, may take a while though.

Comment: Still in the process of installing all add-ons. The tab selector now has black text on gray background, the highlighted line has white text on the same gray background. Change, but no improvement.

Comment: And the debug popup looks just the same as it did before, no change at all.